# создание таблицы на основе существующей

Tags: mysql

Появилась нужна упростить таблицу в mysql для отправки простых данных для arduino.

Что имеется:

```
table: "rack"
colums: "guid", "guid_shop", "name"

table: "shelf_reference"
colums: "guid", "guid_rack"

table: "shelf"
colums: "guid_shelf", "guid_nomenclature"

table: "nomenclature"
colums: "guid", "name"
```

Выбираю я по магазину (guid_shop) в rack, смотрю дальше в shelf_reference список выводимых мне shelf и по тому что там есть смотрю нужною мне nomenclature.

Выходит у меня есть такая структура

```
rack {
   shelf1 {
      nom_1
      nom_2
      ...
      nom_n
   }
   shelf2 {
      nom_1
      nom_2
      ...
      nom_n
   }
   ...
   shelfn {
      nom_1
      nom_2
      ...
      nom_n
   }
}
```

Мне нужно сделать альтернативную таблицу где будут 2 колонки
"guid_nomeclature", "rack_index"
с аналогичной структурой тока в циферном формате

```
1 {
   1.1 {
      1.1.1 \\ должно записываться в колонку "rack_index"
      1.1.2
      ...
      1.1.n
   }
   1.2 {
      1.2.1
      1.2.2
      ...
      1.2.n
   }
   ...
   1.n {
      1.n.n
      1.n.n
      ...
      1.n.n
   }
}
```

И в дальнейшем когда я буду выбирать какую то номенклатуру что бы по "guid_nomenclature" я смог взять
эти 'n.n.n' значения и отправить их на arduino.

Суть вопроса такова, как сделать вот это копирование с конвертацией данных, и в дальнейшем дополнять или удалять их? Направьте на нужный путь))

**UPD**:

fiddle [тык](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef8583c6f23202ad46c4a6c7fbfa806f)

Нужно из данных таблиц сделать новою rack_from_arduino

```
guid_nomeclature    rack_index
9d7e815d-4439-11ea-80e3-0cc47aace875    1.1.1
916a367c-4439-11ea-80e3-0cc47aace875    1.1.1
916a3679-4439-11ea-80e3-0cc47aace875    1.1.1
```

Где 1.1.1 это 1(rack).1(shelf).1(nomenclature)
Ну и дальше соответственно 1.2.1, 1.3.1, 1.3.2 и тд.

Это нужно для отправки на arduino.

Что мне нужно: именно вставка данных в rack_from_arduino, на основе существующих в новом формате.

Comment: *Выбираю я по магазину (guid_shop) в rack, смотрю дальше в shelf_reference список выводимых мне shelf и по тому что там есть смотрю нужною мне nomenclature.* А написать один запрос на базе нескольких таблиц, сразу отдающий нужные данные - не?

Comment: Ну оно все и в одном запросе. Тут вопрос не в этом.

Comment: Ну тогда делайте fiddle (или выкладывайте CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с примером данных) и показывайте требуемый ответ для этих данных с пояснением, почему именно так.

Comment: Вот https://pastebin.com/p0hTY5VQ

Comment: Лучше вот так: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb2f031e9659d6b08716f1e54e0c4ad5). Теперь - что есть желаемый результат... и с подробными пояснениями, почему так (ссылку на fiddle, таблицу-результат и пояснения - добавьте в вопрос).